# Passing of Props in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Following is my JSX code in a React component which is working fine and currently in use, but in most of React blog posts they are also de structuring an object. My query is - do we have any extra benefit of modifying the code to Version 2 or this is just fine.

First Version (currently in use) -

```
const CartItems = ({ items }) => items.length ? items.map((x, i) => (
    <div key={x.id} className={`cart-item-${i}`}>
      <div className="card ">
        <div className="cart-item-img">
            <img src={x.url} alt={x.altText} className="img" />
        </div>
        <div className="cart-item-desc">
            <h3 className="title">{x.title}</h3>
            <p className="text">{x.shortDesc}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="cart-item-action">
            <button className="add">+</button>
            <button className="subtract">-</button>
            <button className="remove">X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>)) : []
```

2nd Version -

```
const CartItems = ({ items }) => items.length ? items.map((x, i) => {
    const {
        id,
        url,
        altText,
        title,
        shortDesc
    } = x;
    return (
    <div key={id} className={`cart-item-${i}`}>
      <div className="card ">
        <div className="cart-item-img">
            <img src={url} alt={altText} className="img" />
        </div>
        <div className="cart-item-desc">
            <h3 className="title">{title}</h3>
            <p className="text">{shortDesc}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="cart-item-action">
            <button className="add">+</button>
            <button className="subtract">-</button>
            <button className="remove">X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>)
    }) : []
```

Comment: I think de structuring of the object is for using each property of that object without accessing that object. You dont have to write user.id, user.name ever time instead, you can use only id and name and so on

Comment: I personally find that destructuring helps in seeing exactly what props a component takes and what their shape is, instead of hunting down each use.

Comment: It's 100% preference or what your team decides on. Just try to stick to one pattern. Personally I prefer to be able to see quickly where a value comes from, so I don't destructure props or state. That way I can see a value being used and immediately know that its either a prop, or state, or a local variable. But I know there's a lot of devs out there that prefer the complete opposite. They prefer to use destructuring as a sort of documentation for the component. You can immediately see what the component requires to work. Just choose one and stick to it.

Comment: Instead of destructuring to serve as the component spec, I prefer using `prop-types` since it goes a step further and also informs the dev of the type of the props required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits are mostly aesthetic and subjective, so if you prefer the first one, more power to you and nothing that says you need to change it.

My personal view on the two snippets you posted: I tend to avoid direct returns from arrow functions because I'll oftentimes need to add a log or something else and having to convert back and forth eventually wears on you. This has little to do with the destructuring though, other than destructuring forces you to have a function body and explicit return.